# Constructing new table by aggregating values in one table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unpivot

I want to generate another table based on the data seen in one table.

```
Customer  product_1      product_2     product_3
  cust_1    0               1            0
  cust_2    1               1            0
  cust_3    1               1            1
```

I am interested in computing the purchase rate for each product.

For example, the purchase rate for product_1 would be

```
(count of (where product_1 = 1)/(count of (where product_1 = 0) + count of (where product_1 = 1))) * 100 

assuming 1 = purchase, 0 = no purchase

i.e. 2/3 * 100 = 66.67
```

The output table should be as follows-

```
 Products       Purchased_quantity      Not_purchased_quantity      Purchase_rate
product_1               2                        1                       66.67
product_2               3                        0                       100
product_3               1                        2                       33.33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and does not require hardcoded names and rather does all dynamically - for any [reasonable] number of product columns ...

```
#standardSQL
SELECT product,
  SUM(purchase) AS Purchased_quantity,
  SUM(1 - purchase) AS Not_purchased_quantity, 
  ROUND(100 * AVG(purchase), 2) AS Purchase_rate
FROM (
  SELECT 
    SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] product,
    CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) purchase
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(REPLACE(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'), '"', ''))) kv
  WHERE SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] != 'Customer'
)
GROUP BY product
```

If to applied to sample data from y our question - the output is

```
Row product     Purchased_quantity  Not_purchased_quantity  Purchase_rate    
1   product_1   2                   1                       66.67    
2   product_2   3                   0                       100.0    
3   product_3   1                   2                       33.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to unpivot and aggregate.  Here is one method:

```
select product, sum(quantity), sum(1 - quantity),
       avg(quantity)
from ((select 'product1' as product, product1 as quantity from t) union all
      (select 'product2' as product, product2 as quantity from t) union all
      (select 'product3' as product, product3 as quantity from t) 
     ) p
group by product;
```

This assumes that the columns are only 0 and 1 -- probably more appropriately called flags than quantities.

Comment: Is there a way to automate the union all statements? I have many product_x columns in the original data